# sum of numbers in 2D list using recursion

Tags: recursion, python

The matrix above is represented like this in Python:

```
m = [[2, 1, 3], 
     [4, 9, 8],      
     [6, 2, 7]]
```

The function should return the following output 2D list.

```
output = [[18, 16, 21],          
         [31, 28, 23],           
         [21, 11, 14]]
```

e.g. 1: for the cell in the first row and first column (2), the sum for 2 across is 2 + 1 + 3 = 6. The sum for 2 down is 2 + 4 + 6 = 12. Add across (6) and down (12) and store the value 18 in the corresponding cell in the output.

The function:
def recursive(m, output, row, col):

base case

reduction step - valid cell => process across and down and compute total

How to solve this with recursion method?

Comment: (1) This appears to be a programming issue, not a mathematics issue. As such it would be better asked in one of the programming forums. (2) It is not at all clear what you are doing. You explain how to get $18$ in the upper left corner, but following the same procedure (sum of row + sum of column) on other fields gives different results than you list. Clearly you've not bothered to fully specify the procedure. (3) At least for the part you have explained there is nothing recursive about it. What are you trying to recurse?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The formula seems to be: for each [i][j] take the sum of the row right to [i][j] and the column down from [i][j]. Both sums start with the element at [i][j].

Here is a version without recursion:

```
m = [[2, 1, 3],
     [4, 9, 8],
     [6, 2, 7]]

def strange_sum(m):
    return [[sum(m[i][j:]) + sum([m[k][j] for k in range(i, len(m))]) for j in range(len(m[i]))] for i in range(len(m))]

print(strange_sum(m))
```

Output: `[[18, 16, 21], [31, 28, 23], [21, 11, 14]]`

To involve recursion, one could calculate the row and column sums separately:

```
def recursive_row_sum(m, i, j):
    if j == len(m[i]):
        return 0
    else:
        return m[i][j] + recursive_row_sum(m, i, j+1)

def recursive_col_sum(m, i, j):
    if i == len(m):
        return 0
    else:
        return m[i][j] + recursive_col_sum(m, i+1, j)

def recursive_sum(m):
    return [[recursive_row_sum(m, i, j) + recursive_col_sum(m, i, j) for j in range(len(m[i]))] for i in range(len(m))]

print(recursive_sum(m))
```

Still another recursive approach could calculate the value at [i][j] as the sum of the values 1 to the left and 1 below minus the value diagonal below. Then summing m[i][j] twice and subtract m[i+1][j] and m[i][j-1].

```
def f(m, i, j):
    s = 2 * m[i][j]
    if i < len(m) - 1:
        s += f(m, i + 1, j) - m[i + 1][j]
    if j < len(m[i]) - 1:
        s += f(m, i, j + 1) - m[i][j + 1]
    if i < len(m) - 1 and j < len(m[i]) - 1:
        s -= f(m, i + 1, j + 1)
    return s

def recursive_sum_bis(m):
    return [[f(m, i, j) for j in range(len(m[i]))] for i in range(len(m))]

print(recursive_sum_bis(m))
```